# Processes currently run by users

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am looking for a [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) command or a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script to get the processes currently run by users in the system.
I tried the `ps -Af` command, however, all the processes including the root processes pop up. 
Is there any command to get the processes run only by user? Otherwise I need some help in writing a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script to take out the root processes from the `ps -Af` command.

Comment: pipe the results through grep.

Comment: @Preet: For that to be useful, you'd need to show a way to check just the username and not match filenames and commander-line arguments.

Comment: Question belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `root`, just do your `ps -Af` and pipe it though grep:

```
ps -Af | grep -v root
```

Of course, this is sloppy.  If you're running a program called troot, you'll lose that as well.  You can be more precise using `awk` and removing any line that has root in the right column.  I don't have the output from `ps -Af` in front of me, but for the sake of argument, let's assume the userid is in the 3rd column.  In that case, you'd want to do this:

```
ps -Af | awk '$3 != "root" { print $0 }'
```

Comment: On my system the user is in the first column, so a simple `ps -Af | grep -v '^root'` would do.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you every process NOT owned by root:

```
ps -N -u root
```

Answer (score 1):

`ps --deselect -U root`. The `--deselect` inverts the logic of `-U root`.

Answer (score 0):

how about `ps -U <username>` (works on MacOSX) or pipe through grep

`ps -Af | grep -v 'root'` should show all processes not owned by root. But beware, grep will not be limited to the username. A process exposing some path containing "root" will also be removed from the result.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try
`whowatch`

It gives you a nice overview of which users are logged in, which processed they currently run and so on

Answer (score -1):

`ps -Af | grep -v root` is not perfect.
try `ps -Af | awk '$1 != "root" {print $0}'`